# How to get Java to ignore negative values in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm creating a program that allows to print out a shopping list based on user input.

I'm trying to add user validation so when you enter a negative price for the product, it'll ask the user to enter a value again since you cannot add a negative price.

Whilst the console does work and ask the user to enter another value when you give it an invalid value, it still adds the negative value into the array which subsequently adds the negative value into the total amount when you pay for it.

Is there a way I can make my code ignore the negative value and not add it into the arraylist? I'm only starting out so it'll help a lot.

*While Loop*

```
    // while loop until user enters the product
    while (true) {

        // asks user for product input
        System.out.print("Please enter product name or enter 'x' to finish: ");
        product = sc.nextLine();
        // terminates the loop if the user enters x
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
            break;

        // asks user for the price of the product
        System.out.print("Enter the price for " + product + " : ");

        price = sc.nextDouble();
        // if user enters negative price it'll be rejected

        if (price < 0)
            System.out.print("Price cannot be a negative value, please enter price again: ");
        sc.nextLine();
        // adds product and price to array lists
        products.add(product);
        prices.add(price);

    }
```

*Adding total to array list:*

```
//method to get the total of the shopping list
public static double getTotalList(ArrayList<Double> prices) {

    // variable that stores the total
    double total = 0;

    // add to the total
    for (double i: prices)
        total += i;

    // return the total
    return total;
}
```

Comment: You can move the two lines after `sc.nextLine()` into an `else` condition above it. And for the sum, `total += i < 0 ? 0 : i` should do the trick.

Comment: I just made those couple of edits as suggested but i found it just adds to the total: @aksappy

*Balance should be $0 as i only have $3 to spend on a $3 product* 

Product 
milk = $ -3.00 
Total Due: $ -3.00
Gift Card:  $  3.00
Gift Card Balance: $  6.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reject negative prices, you should implement reading of `price` in the loop as suggested in the answer by @Renis1235 or you could use a recursive method to read the price until valid value is entered:

```java
static double readValidPrice(Scanner sc) {
    double price = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.nextLine(); // skip line break

    if (price < 0) {
        System.out.print("Price cannot be a negative value, please enter price again: ");
        return readValidPrice(sc); // recursive call
    }
    return price;
}
```

Then call this method from the main loop:

```java
while (true) {

    // asks user for product input
    System.out.print("Please enter product name or enter 'x' to finish: ");
    product = sc.nextLine();
    // terminates the loop if the user enters x
    if (product.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
        break;

    // asks user for the price of the product
    System.out.print("Enter the price for " + product + " : ");

    price = readValidPrice(sc); // valid value is guaranteed to be read

    // adds product and price to array lists
    products.add(product);
    prices.add(price);
}
```

This approach should provide valid values in `prices` list therefore the total sum should be correct.

However, to enforce filtering out negative values in method `getTotalList` you could add the check for price too.  An example using Java Stream API is as follows:

```java
public static double getTotalList(List<Double> prices) {
    return prices.stream()
             .filter(price -> price > 0.0)
             .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue) // DoubleStream
             .sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what should you do if user provide negative value again would you like to ask them to renter till get valid then you need to put this in while loop
if (price < 0)
System.out.print("Price cannot be a negative value, please enter price again: ");

till user inter valid value or you can ignore that value using else statement

or you use if statement in the for each loop to add only the positive one

or use stream but since you just started then maybe you did not get to that part yet

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```java
while (true)
{

    // asks user for product input
    System.out.print("Please enter product name or enter 'x' to finish: ");
    product = sc.nextLine();
    // terminates the loop if the user enters x
    if (product.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
        break;

    // asks user for the price of the product
    System.out.print("Enter the price for " + product + " : ");

    price = sc.nextDouble();
    // if user enters negative price it'll be rejected


    // This is the change, we have a loop which continuously checks if the price is negative, if it is, the user will be asked again
    while (price < 0)
    {
        System.out.print("Price cannot be a negative value, please enter price again: ");
        price = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    // adds product and price to array lists
    products.add(product);
    prices.add(price);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you want to ignore negative input, rather you only want positive input.

Create a method that handles this concern:

```
double getPrice(Scanner sc, String description) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(description + " : ");
        double price = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        if (price >= 0)
            return price;
        
        System.out.print("Price cannot be a negative value");
    }
}
```

then to use it:

```
double price = getPrice(sc, "Enter the price for " + product;
```

This approach handles any number of invalid prices, and make the main code easier to read.